# Changing the default start location of a map in keper.gl

Tags: python, kepler.gl

No matter where you data are located on the map, each time a kepler.gl map is visualised, the starting location is by default `San Francisco`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from keplergl import KeplerGl

df = pd.read_csv("<dataset.csv>")
# df contains data in France
map_1 = KeplerGl(height=400, data={"data_1": df}, config=config)
map_1
```

`map_1` will look like:

[image: default location of the Kepler.gl map, regardless of the data location]

Which means that you have to manually pan to where the uploaded data are in the map (to France in this case).

Is there a way to change the default starting point to where the data are located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution shortly after posting the question:
The initial coordinates can be embedded in the config dictionary:

```
custom_config = {
  "version": "v1",
  "config": {
    "visState": {
      "filters": [],
      "layers": [],
      "interactionConfig": {}
    },
    "mapState": {
      "bearing": -4.928571428571431,
      "dragRotate": True,
      "latitude": 52.253971373306165,
      "longitude": -2.6899063817571394,
      "pitch": 49.18440507924836,
      "zoom": 6.655984704565685,
      "isSplit": False
    },
    "mapStyle": {
      "styleType": "muted_night",
      "topLayerGroups": {},
      "visibleLayerGroups": {
        "label": False,
        "road": False,
        "border": False,
        "building": False,
        "water": True,
        "land": True
      }
    }
  }
}

map_1 = KeplerGl(
    height=800,
    config=custom_config
)
map_1
```

Note that if the config dictionary is defective, then the value will be set to the standard ones with no warnings raised.

Comment: Works! do you happen to know if the config documented somewhere?